# Using compiler variable as key in index wizard don't work

Tags: install4j

With intall4J, I created an **index wizard**. To define steps **Key/Values** (step name), I used compiler variables.
The **Index wizard** is showed correctly. Compiler variable works fine for values (steps name).

---

### **Case 1**

- Using compiler variable to define Key in **Index Wizard** -> **Steps**
- Using compiler variable in **Initial key**, **Step key**.

The step is not activated

---

### **Case 2**

- Using compiler variable to define Key in **Index Wizard** -> **Steps**
- Use the same values as those defined in the compiler variables in **Initial key**, **Step key**

The step is activated

---

Is there a way to use compilation variables to change the index?

(Install4J version: 6.1.6)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the bug report. This will be fixed in 9.0.6. Please ask support@ej-technologies.com for a build where this fix is already implemented.